# Setting a tag for UIAlertController in SWIFT?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

How to set tag for the alert view in swift. I couldn't set the tag `alert.tag = 1`, if I did, I get an error like `'UIAlertController' does not have a member named 'tag'`. Below is the code that i have written,

```
var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "YES", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler:{ (ACTION :UIAlertAction!)in }))
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "NO", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler:{ (ACTION :UIAlertAction!)in }))

alert.tag = 1 // Error is shown here

self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

We used to set tags for alert views in Obj-C. Could someone please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should use the `handler` block to perform the action for a button. the `tag` flag is not available for the `UIAlertController`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like the answer from @Fogmeister and wanted to add:

The only reason you want to use a `tag` on an alert view is to identify it so that you can differentiate which one is calling the delegate method (without the overhead of storing each potential in a property and checking all the pointers). This isn't ideal, but it's a quick work around, and as stated previously it's usually a hack of some kind.

The whole delegation approach is replaced in `UIAlertController` with a block based interface so there should no longer be any need to use the `tag`. The blocks you supply to the alert actions can reference `self` with dedicated code and can capture any local variables you need to so there should be no need to do the same thing that you might have been using a tag for previously.

Comment: This is exactly I was trying to do. I wanted to use tags because I had 2 alert views and wanted to call the delegate method based on the alert view. Now, since the whole delegation approach has been replaced, it makes smooth and easy. 

Thanks much Mr.Wain for the advice. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 5):

`UIAlertController` doesn't have a property `tag`. The hint is in the error "'UIAlertController' does not have a member named 'tag'".

`UIAlertController` is not a subclass of `UIView` it is a subclass of `UIViewController`.

There are almost no reasons for ever using `tag` though, even when it is available.

What you probably want is to set it into a property instead.

Comment: Okay, I could use it that way. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: there are many situations when the tags are extremely helpful, in case of e.g. multiple tableviews with the same delegate, multiple text fields with delegate, etc...

Comment: That may be the case but I don't think I've seen a single example of using tags where something else can be used and IMO is a better way of doing it. I suppose it's personal opinion more than anything though.